# How to save "Export for Screens" settings

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I use the Export for Screens feature to make the various needed resolutions for iOS devices. Since this project targets iOS, iPadOS and macOS, it's a lot of sizes, like 9 or 10. It doesn't save these between sessions. This make tweaking and reexport very tedious.

Is there any way of making this less onerous? I don't see a way to save them.

I'm using Illustrator 2021.